# Windows 7 RC1 to RTM

Tags: windows

I will be installing windows 7 Professional purchased from microsoft.  Following your example discussing the upgrade from RC1 to RTW will I have problems with the install since I will trying to upgrade or rather downgrade windows Ultimate to windows 7 Professional.  I would sincerely appreciate any input you can provide.  My reason for asking this is due to the fact that I have very successively used RC1 as my primary operating system since it was made available to the general public.  Have only experienced a couple of minor problems to date.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the Windows 7 installer won't let you downgrade.  However, there is a hack that will allow you to do it.  The instructions are [here](http://www.unawave.de/installation/downgrade-en.html?lang=EN).

That being said, I would advise a fresh install.  Good luck.

Comment: fresh installs are 99.999% of the time better than trying to futz with an "upgrade" install. Though of course, they do require a little extra work to preserve desired settings and whatnot (though a lot of that can be mitigated by re-pointing all your "My" folders and storage to a seperate harddrive from your OS installation).